# WordPress: How to apply custom CSS class to the root UL using wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I use WordPress 4.1.1 and want to apply custom CSS class to the root `ul` element. To render my menu I use `wp_nav_menu` function:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'top-menu', 'menu_class' => 'my-menu')); ?>
```

According to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), I use `menu_class` option to customize `ul` class. Unfortunately, I have the following markup:

```
<div class="my-menu"><ul>.....</ul></div>
```

The root `ul` element does not have `my-menu` class.

Answer (score 1):

I like to configure wp_nav_menu() to only output the li elements, allowing me to put any markup I need on the ul

```
<ul class="my-menu">
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'menu' => 'top-menu',
            'container' => false, 
            'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
        );
        wp_nav_menu($args); 
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, johnnyd23. But it was my stupid mistake. I forgot to add pages to the top menu in the admin panel)) Anyway, thank you again!